# Put Border Color React Material Theme

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

How do you put material color theme in border like this code below

```
border: '2px solid (theme.palette.primary.main)',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
 border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`
```

How to access the `theme` object depends on the rest of your code. In a function component this could look like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  /// your style declarations
})
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) for other examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the already defined theme in your component with `useTheme`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default function YourComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
      <div style={{
        width: '200px',
        background: '#D3D3D3',
        height: '200px',
        border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      }}>Div with themed border color</div>
  );
}
```

Find it working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-rain-5iwbq